# Print output from multiple SSH commands running in parallel

Tags: java, ssh, concurrency, stream, jsch

I'm trying to write log tool, that will connect to few servers via ssh, open specified log file and print the result to `System.out.print`. for now, I've achieved getting logs from one source. Starting at `SSHManager` class that just use `Jsch` to achieve that.

```
public void tailLogFile() {
     System.out.println("Starting to monitor logs for " + server.getIp());
     String command = "tail -f " + server.getLogFilePath();
     try {
         Channel channel = getSession().openChannel("exec");
         ((ChannelExec)channel).setCommand(command);
         InputStream commandOutput = channel.getInputStream();
         channel.connect();
         int readByte = commandOutput.read();

         while(readByte != 0xffffffff) {
             readByte = commandOutput.read();
             System.out.print(server.getFontColor().toString() + (char)readByte);
         }
         channel.disconnect();

     } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
 }
```

I'm guessing the rest is irrevelant here, it prints coloured logs from SSH to my `System.out`. But, main purpouse of this program is to log multiple files into one place. So I'v tried following

```
for(SSHManager sshManager : getSshManagers()) {
       sshManager.tailLogFile();
}
```

And it is not working now, it starts to `print` logs from first iteration of `for-loop` and since `while` inside `SSHManager.tailLogFile()` doesn't terminate, it keeps printing logs from the first source. As you can imagine, I'd like those n instances of `SSHManager` to share `System.out` and give me output from all sources at same time. I'm wondering what's the easiest way to achieve that? I need to dive into concurrency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to read all output streams continuously in a non-blocking way.

You can use [`InputStream.available()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#available--), like this:

```
ArrayList<ChannelExec> channels = new ArrayList<ChannelExec>();

ChannelExec channel;
channel = (ChannelExec)session1.openChannel("exec");
channel.setCommand(
    "echo one && sleep 2 && echo two && sleep 2 && echo three");
channel.connect();
channels.add(channel);

channel = (ChannelExec)session2.openChannel("exec");
channel.setCommand(
    "sleep 1 && echo eins && sleep 2 && echo zwei && sleep 2 && echo drei");
channel.connect();
channels.add(channel);

ArrayList<InputStream> outputs = new ArrayList<InputStream>();
for (int i = 0; i < channels.size(); i++)
{
    outputs.add(channels.get(i).getInputStream());
}

Boolean anyOpened = true;
while (anyOpened)
{
    anyOpened = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < channels.size(); i++)
    {
        channel = channels.get(i);
        if (!channel.isClosed())
        {
            anyOpened = true;
            InputStream output = outputs.get(i);
            while (output.available() > 0)
            {
                int readByte = output.read();
                System.out.print((char)readByte);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Will get you (assuming Linux server):

```
one
eins
two
zwei
three
drei
```

---

*Note that the answer reads the output by bytes/characters. It does not guarantee, that you get a full line, before switching to another session. So you may end up mixing parts of lines from different sessions. You should accumulate bytes/characters in a buffer, looking for a new line, before printing the buffer to an output.*

Comment: Thanks, it works almost perfectly. I'm testing it at work, and I'm calling services via SOAP requests. Lets say service A calls service B. I should get logs like this: service A - sending request; service B - reciving request. Yet sometimes I got logs like this: B - reciving request; A - sending request. Any chances I can fix that?

Comment: Nothing will guarantee you that the separate servers will push the log records in correct sequence. You would have to sort them locally somehow (by timestamp"). But that would mean that you would have to delay incoming records for some period, in case you get some earlier record later.

Comment: Using concurrency and running all monitored channels on different threads wouldn't improve this a bit? Timestamp would be tricky, one service returns time with miliseconds and another one, don't.

Comment: It can improve it. But it won't guarantee it.

Comment: In this case there is no guarantee that the sequence that is read sequentially from a given stream is aligned with a line (ends with \n ). In particular when lots of lines or very long lines are written to the log files, I'm pretty sure that you will read sections not finishing with a new-line char. As a result you would   mix 2 log entries from different log files. I would suggest to accumulate the content of a stream until you find a new-line char and then you can write a whole line at once. Make sure you keep the un-finished lines from a stream for the next read.

Comment: @MichaelDussere True. I've left that as an exercise to a reader. But I should have mentioned it. Adding Now. +1 to your answer.

Answer (score 1):

As for me, I prefer providing an OutputStream for the channel to write to instead of reading from the InputStream it provides me.

I would define something like that:

```
protected class MyOutputStream extends OutputStream {

    private StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    private Object lock;

    public MyOutputStream(Object lock) {
        this.lock = lock;
    }

    @Override
    public void write(int b) throws IOException {
        this.stringBuilder.append(b);

        if (b == '\n') {
            this.parseOutput();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void write(byte[] b) throws IOException {
        String str = new String(b);
        this.stringBuilder.append(str);

        if (str.contains("\n")) {
            this.parseOutput();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void write(byte[] b, int off, int len) throws IOException {
        String str = new String(b, off, len);
        this.stringBuilder.append(str);

        if (str.contains("\n")) {
            this.parseOutput();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void flush() throws IOException {
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {
        LOGGER.info("My output stream has closed");
    }

    private void parseOutput() throws IOException {
        // we split the text but we make sure not to drop the empty strings or the trailing char
        String[] lines = this.stringBuilder.toString().split("\n", -1);

        int num = 0;
        int last = lines.length - 1;
        String trunkated = null;

        // synchronize the writing
        synchronized (this.lock) {
            for (String line : lines) {
                // Dont treat the trunkated last line
                if (num == last && line.length() > 0) {
                    trunkated = line;
                    break;
                }
                // write a full line    
                System.out.print(line);     

                num++;
            }
        }

        // flush the buffer and keep the last trunkated line
        this.stringBuilder.setLength(0);
        if (trunkated != null) {
            this.stringBuilder.append(trunkated);
        }
    }
}
```

So the usage would be like that:

```
ArrayList<ChannelExec> channels = new ArrayList<ChannelExec>();
Object lock = new Object();

ChannelExec channel;
channel = (ChannelExec)session1.openChannel("exec");
channel.setCommand("echo one && sleep 2 && echo two && sleep 2 && echo three");
channel.setOutputStream(new MyOutputStream(lock));
channel.connect();
channels.add(channel);

channel = (ChannelExec)session2.openChannel("exec");
channel.setCommand("sleep 1 && echo eins && sleep 2 && echo zwei && sleep 2 && echo drei");
channel.setOutputStream(new MyOutputStream(lock));
channel.connect();
channels.add(channel);

for (ChannelExec channel : channels) {
    while (!channel.isClosed()) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
    } 
}
```

The good point is that you benefit to the multithreading already existing in the Jsch channels and then you avoid the problems of a flooding log that won't let the other logs being printed. 
It's also easier and more clear to handle each log with a different stream class.
The StringBuilder is a good way to accumulate the chars until you get a full line.

Remark also that writing a whole line at once avoids to have one function call per char and to multiply the number of written chars with your systematic
    server.getFontColor().toString()

Be sure to lock correctly, the code I wrote is not tested.